# NetBeans VS PhpStorm for PHP development

Tags: php, netbeans, phpstorm

I'm using NetBeans for PHP development and recently i noticed that it's being a bit slower than i would want it to be, when I'm working/navigating in 10-15 projects at the same. And  NetBeans eats a lot of memory.

I started looking for an alternatives. One friend suggested PhpStorm. It's pricy. But based on the PhpStorm description it has all NetBeans features and works much faster.

Is it true? Is it worth it to purchase PhpStorm?

**UPDATE:**

To do a full test a would need to load it 100% it's time consuming. I was hoping that somebody had moved from NetBeans to PhpStoms and can really tell the difference. It's more about performance. Not UI.

Comment: I found PHPStorm to work a little faster. Overall it feels much better . I think you should try for yourself and make your choice based on your experience, since it's a matter of opinion. And PHPStorm is better ;) You have 30 days trial to test it

Comment: @galchen Just updated the post :)

Comment: I seldom find better forums than stackoverflow for info about software 1 vs software 2.. and they are always "closed as not constructive". I know why but a Q&A format for these kinds of questions on stackoverflow would be awesome. :) ^ ^

Comment: PHPStorm behaves very bad with lot of open projects (with 5k+ files). Also, you will need very good hardware and tune the Java parameters and even then it still behaves bad and very often you can't type anymore in the editors. Jetbrains recommends to disable code-highlighting and inspection but also to 'exclude' directories from the project which makes PHPStorm at the end pretty useless. If you really need an reliable IDE for big projects with lots of files, go with Sublime. At least there you can work without crashes and freezes...

Comment: I haven't tried PHPStorm yet, but one of the amazing things you could do is testing with Vagrant http://blog.loftdigital.com/phpstorm-phpunit-and-vagrant (I was looking for some IDE to do so)

Comment: PHPStorm seems like it would be great with all the extra features, but honestly most are half baked.  The SSH sessions aren't added like you would think and saved intelligently.  The add project with existing sources works pretty badly when in comparison to Netbeans it makes a local catch of the files for indexing but then still uploads them.  Honestly you would get more of a benefit from using programs that do that one job nicely.

Comment: PHPStorm is way better after having used Netbeans for quite a while.  The setup is a bit "different", but so far, after about 1 week of switching from 1 year use of netbeans - I am really appreciating PHPStorm - and am finding more and more to like about it.

Answer (score 14):

Well, depends one many factors. I use Netbeans and Notepad++ for smaller projects, and I am happy with both. It is true, that Netbeans is slower, but I find PHPStorm too pricy just to get a very minor advantage over Netbeans. You could try the [demo version](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/index.html) of PHP Storm or read this [feature comparison](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-i-chose-my-programming-editor/).

Comment: Thank you for the link. But it's not very well-written :) When author says `"It seems to tax the processor a bit more, though"` sounds a bit vague.. doesn't it?

Comment: I guess you right, but the overall guide, is that.. if PHPStorm will not cost you an arm or a leg, then go for it, otherwise, stick with Netbeans. :)

Comment: I lost another hour because of netbeans and decided to switch to PHPStorm lol... 50$ sounds cheap after all the crap I've been facing with netbeans

Comment: Just installed Netbeans 8.1. Much faster than PhpStorm 9

Comment: So far, I prefer Netbeans, but I wish it highlighted/hinted my MySQL queries like PhpStorm does after setting up the database connection.

Comment: as a 9 year Netbeans user, I got frustrated with slowness, especially in js files.  I tried PHPStorm and i found several issues with PHPStorm, and went back to Netbeans. 1. can't open two projects in the same window without attaching the 2nd project to the first.  this messed up IDE since my two projects are a local version of the website, and a copy of the remote version.  PHPStorm kept telling me my classes were duplicated.  2. Diff functionality is worse in PHPStorm.  Can't diff two files that are currently open.  very annoying.